# Unity3d - Multiple Selection Toggle Group UGUI

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, toggle

I'm making a GUI for a program and I want the user to be able to pick from two of 7 choices. Is there a built in way to do this or do I need to do it from scratch myself? I read the documentation for Toggle and Toggle group and didn't see anything in there but I might be missing something either there or in another GUI element.

Edited to add: Unity3d 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured it out yet...
I have not tried this myself, but I imagine you could write a script for the toggles in place of using toggle group. I would try messing around with something along the lines of..

```
public void MyToggles()
{
     if (ToggleOptions > 2)
     {
     //code to uncheck the last checked item
     }
}

public void ToggleOptions()
{
//code here to group together your toggles
}
```

That's how I would approach this problem. As I said before I haven't needed this functionality so I cant say for certain how you would do that off the top of my head, but I hope that helps!